# Pesquisa - Proposta de pesquisa por REGEX

Tags: novo-recurso

Estava eu querendo realizar uma pesquisa no SOpt por uma resposta que a muito tempo tinha visto, mas não me lembro em qual pergunta foi feita, apenas lembro de parte da resposta, e das `tags` envolvidas.

Assim fui a pesquisa da mesma, e analisando os modos de pesquisa vi que a maioria não se enquadrava para minha necessidade, ou traziam muitos resultados.

Assim me ocorreu que seria interessante se eu pudesse usar REGEX, pois eu lembro de fragmentes da resposta.

Proposta: Criar uma pesquisa por regex.

#### Exemplo

`regex:/REGEX/FLAG`
ou simplesmente
`regex:REGEX` aplicando sempre as flags `g`,`i`,`m`

Comment: Relacionado: [Como fazer uma busca?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/searching)

Comment: Compreensível. Mas vale a pena a leitura do link para a maioria das pessoas pois essa página é pouco divulgada.

Comment: Guilherme, você tá ligado que o pessoal que sabe RegEx é tipo [O homem que sabia Javanês](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/O_homem_que_sabia_javanês)? Isso dito, grande idéia ;) Oh, yes, o Google é bem melhor pra esse tipo de pesquisa "só lembro um detalhe"...